# Why is my email type input not showing saved/used email adresses?

Tags: html, forms, input

I have label and input elements nest in a div. The input type="email" and the label's for attribute is the same as the inputs id. The problem is that when I click on the input element it doesn't show prviously used email adresses, as it usually does.

```
 <div>
   <label for="email-adress">Email:</label>
   <input type="email" name="email-adress" id="email-adress" />
 </div>
```

When I set name="email"(the same as the label's for attribute) it works, but the thing is that even if i remove the type attribute from the input element, it still shows used email adresses. Why is that?